# Is it okay to use Least Squares Regression when comparing neural network accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, least-squares-svm

I am comparing graphs of neural network accuracy for a study I am doing. I know you could use 5x2 cv and McNemars t-test however I already did the training without folding and this is not a binary prediction. I want to know if using least squares regression would be an acceptable replacement

Comment: What would be your outcome $y$, and what would be your feature(s) $X?$

Comment: x = accuracy outcome = the LSR line for the accuracy

Comment: How do you measure the LSR line?

Comment: I am using the amount of backpropagations the network has completed over time for measurement